# out of memory at line number x

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Getting `out of memory at line number 256` error from Firefox and IE8.

I have cleared all the browser Cache still getting error.

After running the site half and hour later I'm getting this error in alert box.

Is it related to browser issue or server issue?

Edit:

It is seems to be a `respond.js` issue.

Comment: It would be on the client-side where the memory issue is ocurring. Are you able to provide an example of the source code around line 256?

Comment: How much memory does the machine have? What is it doing that would make it run out of memory? Is it custom code or a library? It sounds like a memory leak (not cleaning up old variables).

Comment: Did *you* write the site you're talking about?

Comment: This feels like an "infinite loop" problem. If you remove respond.js do you still get the error? The best approach to finding this problem is to start removing JavaScript from your page, piece by piece.

Comment: @Greg you are correct. Under the Respond.js, there is a loop. Its creating a problem. To support media queries in IE8 (Responsive design) we are using Respond.js. So we cant remove it. When we are using v1.1 its giving memory issue but if we are using v1.4, its giving flickering issue on each menu click of IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps given below:

1. Close anyInternet Explorer or Windows Explorer windows that are currently open.
2. Open Internet Explorer by clicking the Start button , and then clicking Internet Explorer.
3. Click the Tools button, and then click Internet Options.
4. Click the Advanced tab, and then click Reset.
5. Select the Delete personal settings check box if you would like to remove browsing history, search providers, Accelerators, home pages, and InPrivate Filtering data.
6. In the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box, click Reset.
   7.When Internet Explorer finishes applying default settings, click Close, and then click OK.
7. Close Internet Explorer.

This may help you.

Comment: Step 8: Install a different browser :P

Comment: @naveen This is a good explanation for clearing cache and reset browser.